# Why are there missing packages from my distro's groupinstall?

Tags: fedora, package-management, mate-desktop

I am running the XFce Desktop and wanted to install MATE.

I found the group name:

```
yum grouplist | grep -i mate
   MATE Desktop
```

And tried to perform an install but several "group packages" were missing as well as package conflicts.

Why would there be missing packages and conflicts for a distro's own install group?

I am running Fedora 30 with all updates. This installation was done originally from an XFce spin.

```
yum groupinstall "MATE Desktop"
Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:54 ago on Fri 20 Sep 2019 01:17:51 PM EDT.
No match for group package "xorg-x11-drv-omap"
No match for group package "xorg-x11-drv-armsoc"
No match for group package "powerpc-utils"
No match for group package "lsvpd"
Error: 
 Problem: problem with installed package fedora-release-30-5.noarch
  - package fedora-release-30-5.noarch conflicts with system-release provided by fedora-release-matecompiz-30-1.noarch
  - package fedora-release-matecompiz-30-1.noarch conflicts with system-release provided by fedora-release-30-5.noarch
  - package fedora-release-30-1.noarch conflicts with system-release provided by fedora-release-matecompiz-30-1.noarch
  - package fedora-release-matecompiz-30-1.noarch conflicts with system-release provided by fedora-release-30-1.noarch
  - conflicting requests
  - package fedora-release-30-5.noarch conflicts with system-release provided by fedora-release-matecompiz-30-5.noarch
  - package fedora-release-matecompiz-30-5.noarch conflicts with system-release provided by fedora-release-30-5.noarch
  - package fedora-release-matecompiz-30-5.noarch conflicts with system-release provided by fedora-release-30-1.noarch
  - package fedora-release-30-1.noarch conflicts with system-release provided by fedora-release-matecompiz-30-5.noarch
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the "--skip-broken" flag at the end and the command will complete the installation:

```
dnf install @mate-desktop-environment --skip-broken
```